# Different authentication mechanisms for different asp.net web api controllers

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I am building a RESTful webservice using ASP.NET web api. I have 2 controllers, for one controller I want to use Basic auth and for the other controller I want to use token based authentication. Is this possible?

thanks,
Pradeep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up creating two MessageHandlers. One to do Basic auth and the other to do Token based auth. Then I set up per-route messagehandling as shown below:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "BasicAuthApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { controller = "controller1" },
            handler: new BasicAuthMessageHandler() { InnerHandler = new HttpControllerDispatcher(config) }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "TokenAuthApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { controller = "controller2" },
            handler: new TokenAuthMessageHandler() { InnerHandler = new HttpControllerDispatcher(config) }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Thats in my opinion the better solution instead of using filters. I do it the same. I setup my handlers per route. authentication should be done in handlers not filters.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the new authentication filters in Web API v2. They are specifically made for the purpose to annotate controllers or actions with authentication methods.

Either you implement the authentication method right into the controller - or use OWIN/Katana to call back into authentication middleware.

See here for Basic Authentication middleware:
https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/tree/master/source/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin/Basic%20Authentication

Comment: I deleted my answer which is based on using `ClaimsAuthorizationManager` to look at authentication type. I guess using authentication filter is a much cleaner solution.

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the right direction. I ended up using messagehandlers instead of filters.

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about asp.net but on asp.net core we can easily do it, in services add authentication with multiple schemes and set one as default

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

})
.AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthHandler>("BasicAuthentication", null)
.AddJwtBearer(x =>
    {
        x.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
        x.SaveToken = true;
        x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };
    });
```

After this by default JWT is used for authentication, if you want to use Basic Authentication on specific controller or action, we can specify name inside Authorize Attribute

```
[ApiController]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes ="BasicAuthentication")]
public class OtpController : ControllerBase
{
controller code ...
}
```